# Redirect error for question with unicode superscript character at end of title

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

If I try to directly view this question, I get a redirect message (both in Chrome and Firefox, on Windows 10): [Convert kWh to Watts per m²](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487152/convert-kwh-to-watts-per-m%c2%b2)

[image: Redirect error message in Firefox]

I cleared cookies as suggested and there was no change in behavior. I also observe the same issue in Chrome and Firefox on Android.

If I search for the question and find [a link to one of the answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487152/convert-kwh-to-watts-per-m%c2%b2/487155#487155), I can view it no problem.

---

Others in the comments report the same issue, and on a similar question on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394750/redirect-loop-for-special-characters#comment760658_394750), a developer reproduced the issue.

I also discovered that if I switch my phone from WiFi to cellular data, I can open the link.

Comment: Weird, somehow this is a function of my home network (PC on LAN, phone on wifi) -- when I disconnect my phone and go over cellular data, the link loads.

Comment: Confirmed. FF Android. North America. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft4Sq.jpg

Comment: Maybe related with this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394749/578411 ?

Comment: Same problem using Firefox on Ubuntu from Germany - I've reported this on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394750/1116230

Comment: Confirmed by Developer 8 minutes ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394750/redirect-loop-for-special-characters#comment760658_394750

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've removed the affected server from rotation and a build will be going out shortly to address it. We've been testing a branch of our .NET Core port to find issues exactly like this so thanks for the heads up!